# Is there a terraform datasource for accessing all routes in an aws route table?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Data souces for `aws_route_table` and `aws_route` don't seem to make this possible.

Is there a way to get a handle to all routes in an AWS route table with Terraform from a data source?

Comment: Just for clarification, you want to know **all routes** that a routing table has? Right now, I can't think of similar data sources or resources in Terraform ecosystem. I also wanted to look in CloudFormation [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-route-table.html); however, they also don't have that interface.

Comment: What would you need this for? I'm struggling to think of some useful Terraform code that would be able to use this output. If you can explain your problem a little higher up then maybe we can suggest a better approach?

Comment: want to use like this: https://serverfault.com/questions/1011203/is-there-a-way-to-dynamically-update-a-security-group-from-networks-in-a-route-t